# Creating an image from an svg is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I have been trying to create an image (using the `window.Image` class) out of an DataURL. This DataURL contains a svg tag and a foreignObject. But it just stays completely empty.
I also tried to draw this image on a canvas, but I don't think that's the problem since I can't even get a correctly looking image.

**Finished DataURL**

```
data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%3E%3CforeignObject%20width%3D%22100%25%22%20height%3D%22100%25%22%3E%3Cdiv%20style%3D%22background-color%3Ared%22%3Etest%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2FforeignObject%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E
```

**The templated SVG tag**

*NOTE*: A ReactJS Component (`<Component />`) is being parsed to a string. But it does not contain any styles, it's just a simple div with some text in it.

```
const svg = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200"><foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">${renderToStaticMarkup(
        <Component />
    )}</foreignObject></svg>`;
```

**The templated DataURL**

```
const url = `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,${encodeURIComponent(svg)}`;
```

**Loading of the Image**

```
const image = new window.Image(url);
image.src = url;
```

**Image to Canvas**

```
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const image = await loadImage(url) // a simple wrapper function which waits for the image to load that returns a promise
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the finished URL you can see that there is no red background object, I think because the div element is not rendered or not even present.

Try to set xmlns attribute in div element to `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`, like this:

`data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%3E%3CforeignObject%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20x%3D%220%22%20y%3D%220%22%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxhtml%22%20style%3D%22background-color%3A%20red%22%3Etest%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FforeignObject%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E`

example:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">
    <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200">
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="background-color: red">test</div>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Reference:

ForeignObject: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue working on my breathing exercise app. My app logo was supposed to be displayed on the homepage, and wouldn't appear when I tried to add it. Here's what I did to fix it.

Try adding .svg files as a module to your react-app-env.d file.

just add the following line to the list of files there,

```
declare module '*.svg'
```

Then import the file like you normally would,

```
import imageName from './filePath'
```

You should be able to use the svg inside an img tag and have no troubles.